# How to implement live chat functionality in asp.net website

Tags: asp.net

In my application i want to implement live chat functionality where 10 admin users can chat with multiple clients.So please help me to get some sites which are already been coded step by step which can fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement it using signalR and ajax or jquery based plugins.
refer below links to explore more..

- [Simple Chat Application in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8307/Simple-Chat-Application-in-ASP-NET)
- [Building an AJAX based chat
  room in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16201/Building-an-AJAX-based-chat-room-in-ASP-NET)